# Trigger Selenium ide extension on click in react app and parse their data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, selenium

Can anyone tell me how to trigger selenium ide extension?
The following steps are given :

1. Create a UI Screen, it will have input to start recording
2. When clicking on start recording, it will trigger selenium ide
3. Now enter the URL and web browser to be opened
4. Record some scene
5. Stop the recording on the UI screen
6. the output of the above step will be getting recorded script
7. read and parse the scripted file and output the list of functions

Comment: ok, good luck with programming your idea, but it's a wrong place to tell the world